# EmberJS / Ember Data customize http header

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data

using ember 1.13.2 with ember data 1.13.4 in conjunction with a rails backend.

according to the ember guides, the following statement should modify the http headers for every XHR request:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "secret key"
  }
});
```

so I added this as coffee script to my application

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend
  headers: {
        "Authorization": "foofoo"
      }
```

and it's included and correctly compiled to javascript.

But the http header isn't extended with the new header at all.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-header-information-to-rest-get-request-using-restadapter/4220/8

The only solution that works is the one with configuring jquery ajax:

```
Ember.$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, oriOpt, jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.setRequestHeader("someHeader", "someValue");
});
```

But I would prefer the ember way

**Update**:

Strange, it now just works with the ember way. just restarted my computer. maybe this was a browser cache issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Ember docs, you seem to be mostly correct. Here's the solution that ought to work, courtesy of [Ember documentation](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/models/connecting-to-an-http-server/#toc_custom-http-headers)

> Some APIs require HTTP headers, e.g. to provide an API key. Arbitrary headers can be set as key/value pairs on the RESTAdapter's headers property and Ember Data will send them along with each ajax request.

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  headers: {
    'API_KEY': 'secret key',
    'ANOTHER_HEADER': 'Some header value',
    'AUTHORIZATION': 'secret key'
  }
});
```